# trying to understand expects / with with phpunit

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

From https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html :

```
    // Set up the expectation for the update() method
    // to be called only once and with the string 'something'
    // as its parameter.
    $observer->expects($this->once())
             ->method('update')
             ->with($this->equalTo('something'));
```

If the `->with()` is supposed to represent the parameters that are being passed than why is the `$this->equalTo` necessary? What other methods could one use there and why would one want to? As is it seems like this method of calling a mock update method is unnecessarily terse and would be better written as `->with('something')`.

And why do you have to do `->expects($this->once())` to ensure that the method is only called once? If you call a method / method mock once how is it all of a sudden going to be called multiple times?

If I do `strpos()` it's not going to be called 5x times - it's going to be called once. Saying `->expects($this->once())` just seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You need the `$this->equals` in the `->with()` arguments because you can specify different assertions to check the arguments with.  You don't have to have a `$this->with()` for the method, that implies no arguments or that you don't care about them.

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertThat.tables.constraints

One that I will use regularly is `$this->isInstanceOf()` for checking the type of object that is passed to the mocked method.

Similarly for `$this->once()`, there are quite a few ways to specify how many times the mock gets called.

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects.tables.matchers

If you don't care how many times at all just use `$this->any()` (though this will pass if the method is not called).  I tend to use `$this->exactly()` and `$this->once()` so that I ensure that method is called the number of times that I expect.  For testing error cases, `$this->never()` is useful particularly when paired with happy path test.  So that I am specifying what steps should not be happening when something goes wrong.

Having to specify the number of times a method gets called seem to be a little overkill but if you are writing data or performing a resource intensive operation, you are going to want to make sure that it is done once and not 5x which would affect performance.  Specifying the once ensures that if someone modifies your code and they call the method again that the test will fail.